# How to pass Fire store ref object to another activity(Kotlin)?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a Firestore reference in my MainActivity like this:

```
val ref = baseRef.collection("intermediate").document("choicesdocument").collection("choices")
```

Now I want to pass this **ref** reference variable to another activity say SecondActivity **via intent**, so how I can do such a thing?

Also, how can I **retrieve** the data in the second activity?

Comment: why would you want to do that ? why not just recreate the object in the other activity?

Comment: if i do that then i have to create severals reference too, as i am making many different database calls, In this question i broke down my problem to only one database call

Comment: so then don't use a new activity, use one activity with fragments

Comment: brother can you answer to this question only, plus if  you have time i can discuss my project problem with you then you can know my situation here and possibly you  give some other solution

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with creating the same reference in multiple activities. When you interact with Firestore, a single connection between your application and Firebase servers is opened. From that moment on, all traffic between the application and the database goes over that connection. So it doesn't matter how many times you create an instance of Firestore, it will always be a single connection.

As @a_local_nobody already mentioned in his comment, there is no need to pass a reference to the second activity, since it can be simply created there. Besides that, your `ref` object is of type [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference), a class that extends [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query). Unfortunately, none of these classes implement the [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface. This means that you cannot add such an object to an Intent and get it back in the second activity using [getSerializableExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)).

If you want to use a modern solution, then you can use [Hilt for Android](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android). So you can create such an object only once, and then you can inject that instance in which activity/fragment you want.